# Insert Ad in Wordpress Post beside first paragraph

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Hello Javascript and Wordpress Expert,

I am having a small issue, I found a code on the internet. That display the ad in the content of my wordpress blog after x number of paragraph. I tried with 1 and 2 and it works perfectly fine.

Now i would like to display the ad before first paragraph. but i am unable to move the ad beside first paragraphy. i am using a div and float:right to its displaying the ad and its displaying beside 2 or 3 paragraph which is fine. but i need beside first paragraph.

for a sample you can refer this link : http://www.designsmag.com/vintage-clothing-fashion-in-europe/

Here is the code i added in the function php file and hope one of you can help me with this as for you its a piece of cake.

```
function prefix_insert_post_ads( $content ) {

$ad_code = '<div style="float:right; width:336px;">

<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>

"my ad code here"

</script>

</div>';

if ( is_single() && ! is_admin() ) {
    return prefix_insert_after_paragraph( $ad_code, 1, $content );
    }

    return $content;
}
```

// Parent Function that makes the magic happen

```
function prefix_insert_after_paragraph( $insertion, $paragraph_id, $content ) 

{

    $closing_p = '</p>';
    $paragraphs = explode( $closing_p, $content );
    foreach ($paragraphs as $index => $paragraph) 
    {

        if ( trim( $paragraph ) ) {

            $paragraphs[$index] .= $closing_p;

        }

    if ( $paragraph_id == $index + 1) {

        $paragraphs[$index] .= $insertion;

    }


}

return implode( '', $paragraphs );



}
```

Comment: anyone can help me with this

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. instead of checking the closing tag /p check the opening tag `<p>` and that works for me.

Thanks for all your support.

```
$closing_p = '</p>';
```

change to

```
$closing_p = '<p>';
```

Hope that will work for you as  well.